# Tricky Null Pointer exception on an Injector in BaseActivity

Tags: java, android, nullpointerexception, dagger

-Github Api calling Android app

App uses Dagger and build with no error but crashes immediately on launch of app. In the stack stack trace it says that its the Injector and its null as it calls inject passing in the  activity.

[image]

At first I was thinking it was Dagger but then I realised the code is getting generated for what i need so dont think its that

i then checked the manifest where I declared the name of the application as it was crashhing on launch and that what it mostly says on stackoverflow I've been there done that so it not that which leads me to being puzzled as I''m sure someone with more knowhow would see it immediately.
Activity----------------------------------------

```
public abstract class BaseActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    private static String INSTANCE_ID = "instance_id";
    private String instanceId;

    @Inject ScreenInjector screenInjector;
    @Inject ScreenNavigator screenNavigator;


    private Router router;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        if(savedInstanceState != null) {
            instanceId = savedInstanceState.getString(INSTANCE_ID);

        } else {
            instanceId = UUID.randomUUID().toString();
        }

        Injector.inject(this);
        setContentView(layoutRes());

        ViewGroup screenContainer = findViewById(R.id.screen_container);
        if(screenContainer == null) {
            throw new NullPointerException("Activity must have a view with the id of screen_container");
        }
        router = Conductor.attachRouter(this, screenContainer, savedInstanceState);
        screenNavigator.initializeWithRouter(router, initialScreen());
        monitorBackStack();

        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    }


    @LayoutRes
    protected abstract int layoutRes();

    protected abstract Controller initialScreen();

    @Override
    protected void onSaveInstanceState(@NonNull Bundle outState) {
        super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
        outState.putString(INSTANCE_ID, instanceId);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBackPressed() {
        if(!screenNavigator.pop()) {
            super.onBackPressed();
        }
    }

    public String getInstanceId() {
        return instanceId;
    }

    @Override
    protected void onDestroy() {
        super.onDestroy();
        screenNavigator.clear();
        if(isFinishing()) {
            Injector.clearComponent(this);
        }
    }

    public ScreenInjector getScreenInjector() {
        return screenInjector;
    }


    private void monitorBackStack() {
        router.addChangeListener(new ControllerChangeHandler.ControllerChangeListener() {
            @Override
            public void onChangeStarted(@Nullable Controller to,
                                        @Nullable Controller from,
                                        boolean isPush,
                                        @NonNull ViewGroup container,
                                        @NonNull ControllerChangeHandler handler) {

            }

            @Override
            public void onChangeCompleted(@Nullable Controller to,
                                          @Nullable Controller from,
                                          boolean isPush,
                                          @NonNull ViewGroup container,
                                          @NonNull ControllerChangeHandler handler) {
                                        if(!isPush && from != null) {
                                            Injector.clearComponent(from);
                                        }
            }
        });
    }
}
```

Injector-----------------------------------

```
public class Injector {


    private Injector() {

    }

    public static void inject(Activity activity) {

        ActivityInjector.get(activity).inject(activity);

    }

    public static void clearComponent(Activity activity) {
        ActivityInjector.get(activity).clear(activity);
    }

    public static void inject(Controller controller) {
        ScreenInjector.get(controller.getActivity()).inject(controller);
    }

    public static void clearComponent(Controller controller) {
        ScreenInjector.get(controller.getActivity()).clear(controller);
    }
}
```

ActivityInjector-----------------------------------

```
public class ActivityInjector {


    private final Map<Class<? extends Activity>, Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<? extends Activity>>> activityInjectors;
    private final Map<String, AndroidInjector<? extends Activity>> cache = new HashMap<>();


    @Inject
    ActivityInjector(Map<Class<? extends Activity>, Provider<AndroidInjector.Factory<?extends Activity>>> activityInjectors) {
        this.activityInjectors = activityInjectors;

    }


    void inject(Activity activity) {
        if(!(activity instanceof BaseActivity)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity must extend BaseActivity");

        }

        String instanceId = ((BaseActivity) activity).getInstanceId();
        if(cache.containsKey(instanceId)) {
            ((AndroidInjector<Activity>) cache.get(instanceId)).inject(activity);
            return;
        }

        AndroidInjector.Factory<Activity> injectorFactory =
                (AndroidInjector.Factory<Activity>) activityInjectors.get(activity.getClass()).get();

        AndroidInjector<Activity> injector =  injectorFactory.create(activity);
        cache.put(instanceId, injector);

        injector.inject(activity);
    }

    void clear(Activity activity) {
        if(!(activity instanceof BaseActivity)) {
            throw new IllegalArgumentException("Activity must extend BaseActivity");
        }
        cache.remove(((BaseActivity) activity).getInstanceId());

    }

    static ActivityInjector get(Context context) {
        return ((MyApplication)context.getApplicationContext()).getActivityInjector();
    }

}
```

Any elaborations would be greatly welcome links hints or any more info you need just tell me.

[Github Reop](https://github.com/BenMohammad/GitMob)

Comment: why  super.onCreate(savedInstanceState); at bottom of oncreate() method?

Comment: crashes with or without that call there in the onCreate() Shalu thanks though....... it crashes if i put before the if block or even  remove it altogether.